# Customize login process using -- django allauth

Tags: django, authentication, django-authentication, django-apps, django-allauth

I am using `django-allauth` to provide user login and authentication in my django project. And things were going smoothly till now, but I have come across two things which I do not know whether can be implemented in the current app. Any help is appreciated:

1. If we give the following setting `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = True` then after singing up the user account is not active until the user activates the email link. But what I want to do is to allow the user to be logged in, but keep the account active temporarily. Let us say if the user does not activate the account using the link within 7 days, the account will be blocked.
2. I want to allow the user to login using both the email and the username, is that possible? According to the current `readme` we can do only one of them.

Any kind of help is really appreciated.

**Update**

I have written a hack for the second problem and if you want you can check that out in my fork of django-alluth https://github.com/sachingupta006/django-allauth

Answer (score 3):

As for the first problem, the Email Confirmations app stores the data the confirmation has been sent; I'd schedule a cronjob that runs every day and deactivates all accounts which haven't been confirmed for 7 days.

Comment: Yes, I am actually that only :)

Comment: @Sachin could you please share how you did that exactly? It would help me (and I am sure others) too.

Comment: @Samudra To do that first you create a custom command that finds out all the user accounts older than a particular number of days and have not been activated, and the you delete them. You can see here, http://andrewwilkinson.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/creating-django-management-commands/ how you can create custom django admin commands. Next you write a cron job that runs this command, say everday, you can check out how to write a cron job here http://glweb.biz/blog/?p=17 If this does not help, then I can tell you in more detail

Comment: Thanks! I think that should suffice.. if not I will comment here again :)